# Can we have overlapping IPv6 addresses on same interface?

Tags: ipv6

Example :

Fast Ethernet 0/0
1900::1/96
1900::20/64

Will there be any issues wrt to such a configuration, I know that this would cause routing issues when such overlaps happen across different interfaces, but these are on the same interface.

Answer (score 1):

You would, of course, have problems with those invalid IPv6 addresses (see [Internet Protocol Version 6 Address Space](http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv6-address-space/ipv6-address-space.xhtml)), but, in general, you can have as many IPv6 addresses in the same subnet as your OS allows (8, 16, 32, etc.).

**EDIT for a host on the network:**

I'm not sure what you mean about problems on different interfaces.  If the interfaces are truly connected to the same subnet, there is no reason not to address them in the same subnet.

**EDIT for a router:**

Of course multiple routed interface in the same network pose a problem, but multiple addresses in the same subnet on the same interface are not a problem. The OS has a limit on the number that you can have on an interface, but up to that limit is fine.

Comment: So if Fa0/0 has 1900::1/96 and Fa0/1 has 1900::20/64 we would have overlapping subnets which would be wrong. But what would be the problem when you have them on the same interface ? Why are the ip addresses invalid ? would they not respond to a ping on the network ?

Comment: By your comment, I see you mean on a router which your question didn't say, so I assumed you meant a PC. If you read my answer, you can have as many addresses in the same subnet on the interface as the OS allows. The problem is your choice of address is invalid and not allowed to be routed. See http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv6-address-space/ipv6-address-space.xhtml for why the addresses are invalid.

Comment: Ok, I understand that the IPv6 addresses cannot be routed. I took it as an example, sorry for the confusion. Sorry to ask again, but what would be the problem if overlapping subnets are configured on the SAME interface ? like in the example above where we have both 1900::1/96 and 1900::20/64 configured on the same interface, the subnets are different.

Comment: Well, in IPv6, all the subnets are /64 so you really don't need to worry about overlapping subnets or different sized subnets like you do in IPv4. Subnets different than /64 will break some IPv6 functionality. As I pointed out above, multiple addresses in the same subnet are perfectly fine. There is actually an IPv6 network set aside for examples that you can and should use: `2001:db8::/32`.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add purely **empiric** observations reproducing such configurations on `Cumulus VX 4.2.1`. It hard for me to justify such a setup nor it seems valid to me, but I'm more than curious to try it.

[image: topo]

`cumulus21` will have this weird IPv6 setup:

```
State  Name  Spd  MTU    Mode          LLDP            Summary
-----  ----  ---  -----  ------------  --------------  ----------------
UP     lo    N/A  65536  Loopback                      IP: 127.0.0.1/8
       lo                                              IP: ::1/128
UP     eth0  1G   1500   Mgmt                          Master: mgmt(UP)
UP     swp2  1G   9216   Interface/L3  cumulus (swp2)  IP: 1900::20/64
       swp2                                            IP: 1900::1/96
```

.. and `cumulus20` has the following interfaces:

```
State  Name  Spd  MTU    Mode          LLDP            Summary
-----  ----  ---  -----  ------------  --------------  ------------------------
UP     lo    N/A  65536  Loopback                      IP: 127.0.0.1/8
       lo                                              IP: ::1/128
UP     eth0  1G   1500   Mgmt                          Master: mgmt(UP)
UP     swp1  1G   9216   Default
UP     swp2  1G   9216   Interface/L3  cumulus (swp2)  IP: dead:beef:cafe::1/64
```

It also has to have a static route since IPs are in different subnets.

```
cumulus@cumulus:mgmt:~$ net show route
show ip route
=============



show ipv6 route
===============
Codes: K - kernel route, C - connected, S - static, R - RIPng,
       O - OSPFv3, I - IS-IS, B - BGP, N - NHRP, T - Table,
       v - VNC, V - VNC-Direct, A - Babel, D - SHARP, F - PBR,
       f - OpenFabric,
       > - selected route, * - FIB route, q - queued route, r - rejected route

S>* 1900::/64 [1/0] is directly connected, swp2, weight 1, 00:07:14
C>* dead:beef:cafe::/64 is directly connected, swp2, 00:08:54
C * fe80::/64 is directly connected, swp1, 00:08:54
C>* fe80::/64 is directly connected, swp2, 00:08:55
```

And as to the ping -- it works for both addresses.

```
cumulus@cumulus:mgmt:~$ ping 1900::1
vrf-wrapper.sh: switching to vrf "default"; use '--no-vrf-switch' to disable
PING 1900::1(1900::1) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 1900::1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.539 ms
64 bytes from 1900::1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.467 ms
64 bytes from 1900::1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.490 ms
^C
--- 1900::1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 6ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.467/0.498/0.539/0.039 ms


cumulus@cumulus:mgmt:~$ ping 1900::20
vrf-wrapper.sh: switching to vrf "default"; use '--no-vrf-switch' to disable
PING 1900::20(1900::20) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 1900::20: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.510 ms
64 bytes from 1900::20: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.488 ms
64 bytes from 1900::20: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.469 ms
^C
--- 1900::20 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 5ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.469/0.489/0.510/0.016 ms
```

Cisco NXOS (tested on Nexus 9000) is a little bit more picky, but I was able to set up the configuration and it also worked just fine.